# Airlock was removed from wine carboy - is it still ok?

Tags: airlock

So we had our basement flood last month and the company that came in to do the repairs moved my wine (6 gallons each of blueberry and apple) and at some point between now and then someone thought it was a good idea to take my airlock out of the glass carboy. Would my wine still be good? It could have been out for up to a month. I've been avoiding the basement like the plague until the we're done.

Answer (score 4):

No way to really know.

For sure it will be more oxidized. It will be a flaw in taste, but no one can know how big one.

Real danger is with flood. Flood promotes mold, and other bad microorganisms. We can't know if some is in your wine, and how much alcohol was there when it got contaminated, if it was. Worst case? Little alcohol, sourness, "toilet" taste, poisonous. Best case? Nothing wrong. There is simply not enough data to tell.